# rasa-core action only returning empty array

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

so I'm trying to make a query bot, in which the user says "Who is Bill Gates" and it uses Wolfram alpha to give the response (for example). I'm using rasa nlu and rasa core and have everything correct but when I run it with my query its only returning [].

I've researched the problem and tried using different versions of rasa core but I can't seem to make any progress. I've checked the API portal and the requests are logging so it seems the only problem is displaying the result.

### stories.md

```
## query
* query
  - actions.query.ActionQuery
```

### domains.yml

```
slots:
  query_object:
    type: text
  relations:
    type: text
  context:
    type: text

intents:
  - query.author
  - query.calories
  - query.height
  - query.height.relation
  - query.person
  - query.person.relation
  - query.person.money
  - query.person.age
  - query.item
  - query.item.released

entities:
  - query_object
  - relations
  - context


actions:
  - actions.query.ActionQuery
```

---

.actions/query.py

```
from rasa_core.actions.action import Action

import requests

class ActionQuery(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_query'

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):


        query_object = tracker.get_slot('query_object')

        print(query_object)

        if tracker.get_slot('relations') : 
            relation = tracker.get_slot('relations')
        if tracker.get_slot('context') : 
            context = tracker.get_slot('context')

        r = requests.get("http://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/result?appid=HJGTTH-4WQG3TEREW&i={}%3f".format(query_object))

        if r:

            res = r.content()

            dispatcher.utter_message("Hey , This is the answer if it shows ... -> " , res)

        else:

            dispatcher.utter_message(" sorry, I couldn't find anything on that ")

        return
```

---

I have got training data and have used Rasa Nlu and trained it and have also trained my Rasa Core files.

Thank you in advance

Comment: which Rasa Core version are you using? And which component (Rasa Core, Action server) exactly returns the empty array?

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using rasa-core version 0.13.5 and I'm pretty sure I'm using rasa-core which returns the array

Comment: I recently tried using the SDK action server and added the localhost:5055... etc to the endpoints.yml file and this still doesn't work

Comment: can you please try to rename the action in your domain file and stories from `actions.query.ActionQuery` to `action_query`? What's your Rasa Core SDK log when you start the server?